How to test Eventarc locally?
I'm considering moving from Cloud Functions for Firebase to a more custom back-end running in Cloud Run. However, our application has many Firestore triggers; for instance, when a user makes a purchase, several events take place like confirmation email etc.
Now, with the Firebase implementation, emulators handle everything automatically as changes in the emulated Firestore trigger emulated functions. In my refactored architecture, I can make an Eventarc trigger that listens for Firestore events and calls a Cloud Run endpoint with the event. This achieves the desired functionality.
But how can I setup my local development environment? Is there a way to make triggers for Eventarc emulator? How can I trigger a localhost request on Firestore event? How do people usually test similar setup locally, or are y'all deploying the application to test the whole?
There's this similar question with the answer "team is working to make the local tests easier". Is there any better workaround than what's suggested there?

Great question and no answer from me. Eventarc is a managed service by Google and you can use it only on Google Cloud. I don't know any emulator equivalent that allows you to test locally (or in your CI/CD for integration tests for instance).

As @guillaume-blaquiere mentioned looks like emulator for eventarc is not available. You may consider raising a Public Issue Tracker for the support of emulator
